# Socket.io conecta mas não envia o emit para o server e vice-versa. Nginx e SSL

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, socket.io

Estou utilizando o Nginx com SSL e essa configuração para um serviço comunicar com o node, quando acesso o endereço o socket.io conecta normalmente com o server mas não recebe o emit nem envia.

```
location ~ ^/(atualizaUltimaPosicao|node|socket\.io) {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/websockets.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/websockets.error.log

      if ($uri != '/') {
        expires 30d;
      }
   }
```

Essa é minha aplicação node, assim que o usuario conecta ela deveria enviar o emit mas no client não chega.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  origins: '*:*'
});
http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening port 3000');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("Client connected");
  socket.emit('posicao', 'test');
  console.log("Sended");
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("Disconected");
  });
});
```

No log da aplicação node ele envia,
Client connected
Sended

Codigo do client:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://mydomain.com.br/atualizaUltimaPosicao');
    if (socket !== undefined || socket !== null) {
        socket.on('posicao', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    }
```

Acredito que pode ser alguma configuração errada que fiz no Nginx mas não sei o que é.

Obrigado pela ajuda.